# Web page cannot be found to display image from server in JSP

Tags: html, image, jsp, hyperlink, href

I am uploading my image in below path and trying to display the same with   tag .I am able to upload image in server but it shows web page cannot be found while displaying.

I am uploading file in below path

```
filePath = "/data/tms/IBM/WebSphere/images/upload/";
```

and accessing as below

```
<img src="/data/tms/IBM/WebSphere/images/upload/myimage.gif"
```

also accessing as below which shows same error

```
<a href="./upload/myimage.gif" target="_blank">
```

Please help me how can display in my html page.

Comment: Check whether your folder is accessible outside your server.

Comment: Can you please tell, how can i check that